# GStreamer pipeline of 2 wav files onto single RTSP with 2 channels

Tags: audio, streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to build a pipeline which I'll give him 2 wav files and stream those 2 as a single RTP, which has 2 channels that each channel is composed of the relative wav file.

I want to send the RTP using RTSP as well in order to do authentication for the RTSP connection.

I've tried using this pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 interleave name=i ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=file.wav  filesrc location=first_audio_file.wav ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw,channels=1,channel-mask=(bitmask)0x1" ! queue ! i.sink_0   filesrc location=second_audio_file.wav ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw,channels=1,channel-mask=(bitmask)0x2" ! queue ! i.sink_1
```

Which helps to take 2 wav files and saves them as a new file.wav in the same directory.
The output of file.wav is the mixing between them and as well he has 2 channels.
I've tried manipulating this pipeline in order to achieve what I've described but the main issue is making the sink to be RTSP with RTP split to 2 channels.

If anyone has a suggestion to solve this, that would be great!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

RTSP is not a streaming transport protocol but a session protocol, so it's completely different from the actual streaming logic (which you can implement with a GStreamer pipeline). That's also why you have a `rtpsink` (which you can use to stream to RTP), but not an `rtspsink` for example.

To get a working RTSP server, you can use for example `gst-rtsp-server`, of which you can find multiple example to set it up in their repo, like [this small example](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/-/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c). Although the examples are all in C, GStreamer also provides bindings to other languages like Python, Javascript, ...

Comment: Hey, actually there's rtspclientsink which which can help out to use RTSP as the session protocol, which afterwards gives RTP data.
The subject that I'm trying to do is that the RTP will be single with 2 channels.

Comment: Heh, TIL about `rtspclientsink`. However, that element also requires a running RTSP server, [as can be seen in this example](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-record.c). Further, you say you want to have a "single RTP with 2 channels"? What do you mean exactly by that? Normally you have an RTSP server return an SDP which contains 2 different RTP streams, so each stream should get their own `rtpsink` if you want them to be in a separate RTP stream

Comment: Hey,
I do have an RTSP server whose listening to RTSP connection so I don't actually need the RTSP server but thanks :) 

Regarding the RTP with 2 channels.
I wish that RTSP will negotiate in its SDP that the RTP that will initiate will be a single one, and that single RTP stream will have inside of it 2 channels.
Which means, that RTP will have 2 SSRCs, for each wav file.